# Excel - VBA: Change the text color of a cell based on the text color of an adjecent cell

Tags: vba, colors, fonts

I am working on a macro that loops through the range dData and identifies which cells have a white font color. Then it changes the font color of any cell adjacent to dData white. The below code is what I have so far. It does not work yet but, am I on the right track?

Thanks!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim dData As Range
Dim Cell As Range

Set dData = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("l2:l10000")

For Each Cell In dData
    If Cell.Font.Color = 2 Then
        Cell.Offset(0, -1).Font.Color = 2
    End If
Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think you want to put this code in the `SelectionChange` event, though.

Comment: I have a combo box that triggers another macro, I might just place this there. Any ideas about why this is not working at the moment?

Comment: Are you getting an error or is it just that nothing happens when you run it?

Comment: Nothing happens when I run it.

Comment: This code affects `Sheet1` regardless of what Worksheet module you place it in. Are you sure you're checking `Sheet1` for the changes?

Comment: I double checked and it is referencing the correct sheet. I'm stumped.

Comment: Are you certain that `2` is the correct color value? That does not seem to be the value for white font, when I run it in Excel 2010.

Comment: I'm working in Excel2007. I will double check the color number.

Comment: It appears to be the correct number for white in 2007. I'm not sure if they are different for font colors.

Comment: Are you able to, in a separate macro, do something like `Range("A1").Font.Color = 2` to verify that the color assignment works as you expect?

Comment: I tried the separate macro and it does not work.

Comment: See revision below, there is a difference between `Color` and `ColorIndex`, I think you need to use the latter.  Thanks @Sid for noticing this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be working for me.

```
Sub Test()
Dim dData As Range
Dim Cell As Range

Set dData = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("l2:l10000")

For Each Cell In dData.Cells
        If Cell.Font.Color = 16777215 Then
            Cell.offset(,1).Font.Color = 16777215
        End If
Next
End Sub
```

**Note** also the scope of `dData` is limited to `Sheet1`

On my computer, "white" is a long value of `16777215` which works for me in 2010 Excel, and I think should work in 2007. In Excel 2003 I am not sure.

TRY THIS

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim dData As Range, aCell As Range

    Set dData = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L2:L10000")

    For Each aCell In dData.Cells
        If aCell.Font.ColorIndex = 2 Then _
        aCell.Offset(, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 2
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. What I am trying to do is test which cells in column "L" have white font and then change the font color ion column "M" to white.

Comment: @user1437463: If you want to chnage the color of Col `M` then why `Offset(0,-1)` ;) Try `Offset(,1)`

Comment: @david: `you will need an extra If statement otherwise cells in Column A will raise an error.` Why this?

Comment: @David: I dont wanna post another answer so I am going to edit your post. Hope you don't mind

Comment: @SiddharthRout feel free :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout will not `[A1].Offset(0,-1)` raise an object required error? It is an illegal range address.  There are no columns to the *left* of column A.

Comment: @DavidZemens Where did "A1" Come from? We are looping cells in Col L ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout my mistake. I used a different range when I was testing  it!

Comment: @user1437463: Please test the updated code at the bottom and tell us if it works?

Comment: Thanks, I'll test this when I get back to my desk!

Comment: It works when I create a new sheet to test it on but when I apply it to the sheet that I am using it does nothing (changed the sheet name). I believe it may be due to the fact that I'm using conditional formatting to color the text in column L white. Does this make sense to anyone?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks to everyone for the help!

Comment: Conditional formatting would probably affect it. I haven't tested it that way though.